# Overriding a magic method in PHP

Tags: php, overriding

I've googled for an hour and found variants of this issue but not this exact version of the problem, except for one blog post that didn't work.

I want to override a method in a PHP extended class, and call the parent inside the body of the new one.  The problem is that the parent does not have such method, but implements `__call()` to expose that functionality.

For example:

```
class B extends A {
  public function setParentId($new_id) 
  {
     parent::setParentId($new_id);
     $this->buildParentTreeCache();
     return $this;
  }
```

This doesn't work. In fact I get a nasty Apache internal error or misconfiguration.

I've found this solution that didn't work either:
(Except I added the `array($new_id)` part. The example used NULL.)

```
class B extends A {
  public function setParentId($new_id) 
  {
     parent::__call('setParentId', array($new_id));
     $this->buildParentTreeCache();
     return $this;
  }
```

This one should have worked!  I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

What's the right way to do this?

Edit:

I'm not sure what's wrong with my configuration, but the error messages I 'm getting here are just:

```
[Mon May 04 12:13:12.778136 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 30512] (104)Connection reset by peer: [client 127.0.0.1:54854] FastCGI: comm with server "/var/www/fastcgi/php5.fastcgi" aborted: read failed, referer: http://admin.mysite/index.php/category/index
[Mon May 04 12:13:12.779620 2015] [fastcgi:error] [pid 30512] [client 127.0.0.1:54854] FastCGI: incomplete headers (0 bytes) received from server "/var/www/fastcgi/php5.fastcgi", referer: http://admin.mysite/index.php/category/index
```

Edit 2:

The base class (Class A in this example) is an autogenerated file that also does not have the code I'm trying to call.

In fact, it's a Doctrine 1 model "Base" class called "BaseCategory" that extends from sfDoctrineRecord.

```
class Category extends BaseCategory // My class
class BaseCategory extends sfDoctrineRecord // Autogenerated, prone to be verwritten by the generator
```

The code for class sfDoctrineRecord is here:

http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.2/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/record/sfDoctrineRecord.class.php

Comment: Can you elaborate on _does not work_? What error are you getting? Check Apache/PHP error logs for a description.

Comment: May be worth knowing: http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php#91315

Comment: You should be able to just call `parent::setParentId($new_id)`, rather than `parent::__call(etc etc)`.

Comment: @JamesSpence Well, see **moonwave99**'s link...

Comment: @moonwave99 ah interesting, I never knew that. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Can you post Class A code please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As moonwave99 suggested, you should have a look **[here](http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.parent.php#91315)**

> Take care of using **parent::method** with not declared method when using
>   __call because in this case the string method will be **lowercase**:

```
<?php
  class A {
      function __call( $method, $args ) {
        echo get_class( $this )  . ' ' . $method . "\n";
      }
  }

  class B extends A {
      function getTest() {
          parent::getTest();
      }
  }

$a = new A();
$a->getTest();
$b = new B();
$b->getTest();

?>

output:

A getTest
B gettest
```

This might be what is causing your error, so when you are doing `parent::setParentId($new_id);` it is likely that it is interpreteded as:

> parent::set**p**arent**i**d($new_id);

Try to use lowercase as well in class A

Comment: Sad issue.  I do not have control over Class A's interface.

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli that is really a problem, if you figure out how to get trought it please let us know. It is very interesting and tough issue!